# conflict in Css using external examples

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie to web design and development.
I see `Code pen` has great examples and I would like to incorporate those examples with my demo sites.
The problem is the Code pen demos have CSS which conflicts with what i am working on.
eg. i downloaded a `Full screen` menu of Code pen and has CSS properties for a and li . it ruins my design.
**How can I fix that?**
thanks

Comment: Change class names.

Comment: @George so you mean i completely change the codepen class names?

Comment: No, I mean your class names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to overwrite the styles you don't need (like li and a) by loading your own CSS after you load the example CSS.

Like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="codepen.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="youroverwrites.css" />
```

If thats not enough, use the !important option. In your own css (which MUST be loaded after the codepen css), use something like this:

```
li { border:red !important };
```

The important thing is: load your own CSS after the stuff you import from codepen. Easy as that.

Answer (score 1):

in your style sheet create custom css and then add in the styles for a and li underneath them.

For example:

```
.container a {
    // insert styles
   }
.list{
   // insert styles
  }
.item{
   // insert styles
   }
```

in your html

```
<div class="container">
  <a class="link"></a>
 <ul class="list">
   <li class="item"></li>
   <li class="item"></li>
   <li class="item"></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a heads up that's not valid CSS